# retrive data from session storage and local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I am storing form values into session and local storage then displaying it.

I have stored name in session storage and local storage then retrieved it and displayed it but the code is not working for the phone number and email address.

```
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
<div id="result4"></div>
<div id="result5"></div>
<div id="result6"></div>
<script>

function details(form) {
  var name = form.name.value;
  sessionStorage.setItem("name", name);
  localStorage.setItem("name", name);
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");
  var Address = form.address.value;
  sessionStorage.setItem("address", Address);
  localStorage.setItem("address", Address);
  document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("address");
  document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("address");
 var phone = form.phone.value;
   sessionStorage.setItem("phone", phone);
   localStorage.setItem("phone", phone);
  document.getElementById("result5").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("phone");
  document.getElementById("result6").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("phone");
}
</script>

<form>
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  Address:<br>
  <input type="text" address="address">
  <br>
  Number:<br>
  <input type="text" phone="phone">
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="button" value="Click" 
    onClick="contact(this.form)">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake is you are not using the name here

```
 <input type="text" name="address"> //change instead of address
 <input type="text" name="phone">//change instead of phone
```

in the input you need to give name for particular inputs

Answer (score 0):

Access the form elements by [HTMLFoprm.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)

Also, make sure that every form element has the name attribute.

```
var name = form.elements['name'].value;
var Address = form.elements['address'].value;
```